# Regarding Mysql Master-slaves configuration

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regarding Mysql Master-slave configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593613/regarding-mysql-master-slave-configuration)

Hi to all,

I have some doubs regarding Mysql master-slaves

For example , if i setup 2 slaves to Master.In between production ,i want to add another slave to that master.at that time,what i have to do?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The process of setting up a slave to a live server is simple:

- use mysqldump to get a snapshot from the master in a specific point in time
- configure your new slave as per your needs, with replication down
- integrate the master snapshot
- shutdown the slave server
- configure replication
- start the slave

You can do all this perfectly well on a running production server, as the only intervention required on existing servers is taking the snapshot from the master which is a rather painless process.